# Python IndentationError - How to fix?

Tags: python, syntax

```
while loop == 6:
if EVENTCOUNT >= 4:
                _, username, para, value = event.split(" ", 3)
                try:
                        self.dbcur.execute('select ? from users where name = ?', [para, username])
                        if rrf is None:
                                print notex
                        else:
                                print str(username)+" has been altered: "+str(para)+" => "+str(value)+"."
                        while loop == 2:
                                again = raw_input("Is that all? (Y/N)")
                        while True:
                                if again == "Y":
                                # edit another parameter
                                        loop=4
                            elif again == "N":
                                    print "Thanks! Bye! \nAll credits of this program go to Trey."
                                    #end program
                                    break
                    else:
                            print "Sorry! That wasn't Y or N."
                            loop == 2
```

I get an the error: "IndentationError: expected an indented block" and there is an error underneath the if EVENTCOUNT >=4:

Comment: 'if' on the second line is not indented.

Comment: Run `python -tt script.py` and fix everything that tells you to fix. In the meantime, your indentation *here* is unusable; we cannot tell actual bad indentation from inexperience with Stack Overflow and Markdown.

Comment: As a best practice, always use 4 spaces instead of tabs for indentation. Always!

Comment: .. unless the existing codebase has another convention.

Comment: And there`s an `elif` that's not endented properly and also an `else` later on.

Answer (score 1):

Use an IDE, which often has an indentation tool for automatically converting mixed tabs and spaces to either all tabs or spaces. Here is your code with 4 spaces per indent.

```
while loop == 6:
    if EVENTCOUNT >= 4:
        _, username, para, value = event.split(" ", 3)
        try:
            self.dbcur.execute('select ? from users where name = ?', [para, username])
            if rrf is None:
                print notex
            else:
                print str(username)+" has been altered: "+str(para)+" => "+str(value)+"."
            while loop == 2:
                again = raw_input("Is that all? (Y/N)")
            while True:
                if again == "Y":
                # edit another parameter
                    loop=4
                elif again == "N":
                    print "Thanks! Bye! \nAll credits of this program go to Trey."
                    #end program
                    break
            else:
                print "Sorry! That wasn't Y or N."
                loop == 2
        except Exception,err:
            print "error"
```

Comment: :) I realize we don't want to rely on tools too much, but an IDE can really speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a consistent indentation for all blocks within a file - I (and [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)) strongly recommend four spaces.

Mixing tabs and spaces in a single file is bad because tabs have variable perceived widths based on the developer's environment. Mixing the number of spaces within a single file can confuse the interpreter.

Comment: Would you link and/or explain PEP8 for the benefit of the OP and future readers?